# How can I do an HTTP benchmark (like ab or siege) to a host with multiple IPs?

Tags: html, linux, apache, benchmarking, apachebench

I'm trying to test my web servers and I have an A record with multiple IPs (each belongin to a different server, in a form of load balancing). When I connect with my browser I get it to randomly connect to each server, but Apache Benchmark and Siege do only use the first IP in the pool, which screws my tests.

I really need to force benchmark to use all IPs.

Comment: Maybe you can request all IPs yourself and start an `ab` test for each of them?

Comment: I do have bad experiences with ab, by the way. It isn't as concurrent as it suggests it is, and in the end it doesn't really stress test your server very much. I've managed to bring a webservice down by holding down F5 in Chrome, while ab couldn't pressure it at all, despite using the various concurrency options. In the end I tried a couple of other tools and ended up writing one myself.

Comment: @GolezTrol could you please share the tools you use to accomplish this in a better way?

Comment: I don't think I still have it, sorry. It wasn't very elaborate or re-usable either, since I just hacked it together for my particular situation.